# Android :: Pick a file with specific extension

Tags: android, kotlin, filechooser, filepicker, scoped-storage

I need to pick a file with specific extension (.jpg, .jpeg, .png and .cv).

I'm trying to make it using standard chooser intent

```
 private fun showFileChooser() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.setType("*/*")
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        val chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(intent, resources.getString(R.string.work_experience_select_file))
        getResult.launch(intent)
    }
```

To retrieve result I'm using this stuff ::

```
     * Activity result callback for Upload Image intent
     */
    private val getResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val uri = it!!.data!!.data

            val path = getPath(requireContext(), uri!!)
            Log.d("dbg", path)
        }
    }
```

It works perfectly when I'm picking files (images) from default Photos directory. In this case picker activity returns Uri, from which I can extract file path.
(content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F33/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/120240746)

But when I'm picking a file from Download directory or another, picker returns Uri, from which I can not extract it.
(content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A34)

For extracting file path I use this code

```
@Throws(URISyntaxException::class)
fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        val projection = arrayOf("_data")
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
            val columnIndex = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data")
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {

        }
    } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        return uri.path
    }
    return null
}
```

So, what my problem is??

P.S. -> I was trying to find some external library, but I didn't find a one which is working with sdk >29 (scoped storage).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958619/why-is-file-canread-method-always-returning-false

Comment: You should not convert URI to file. Just open a Input stream and read image.