# why is file.canRead() method always returning false

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file

I am trying to get a file path and file from uri, but when I do `filePath.exists()` which is `true` but when I check `filePath.canRead()` it is always `false`

any suggestions on why this might be the case please
I have given all permissions

Uri - content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/8555
returned path - /storage/emulated/0/Download/Gmail - Extension quote.pdf
which is the right path I am expecting

any thoughts on why `filePath.canRead()` would be `false` please

```
else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    val id: String
                    var cursor: Cursor? = null
                    try {
                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                            uri,
                            arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME),
                            null,
                            null,
                            null
                        )
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            val fileName: String = cursor.getString(0)
                            val path: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                                .toString() + "/Download/" + fileName
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                return path
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null) cursor.close()
                    }
}
}
```

permission i have given

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also ask for permission

```
//User selected to upload a file
        uploadFileBtn.setOnClickListener {
            // Check if read storage permissions are already granted
            if (askForStoragePermissions(FILE_BROWSER_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)) {
                //Launch file browser app to select PDF file
                openPdfFileBrowser()
            }
        }

private fun askForStoragePermissions(requestCode: Int): Boolean {
        if (!isStoragePermissionsAllowed()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    this.requireActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
            ) {
                showPermissionDeniedDialog()
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this.requireActivity(),
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    requestCode
                )
            }
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Edit
why I need to convert uri to file. need to upload the file to the server

```
private fun uploadFile(sourceFile: File, uploadedFileName: String? = null, model: UtilityBillModel) {
    Thread {
        val mimeType = getMimeType(sourceFile)
        if (mimeType == null) {
            return@Thread
        }
        val fileName: String = uploadedFileName ?: sourceFile.name
        try {
            val requestBody: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("key", model.fieldsToUseInPost.key)
                .addFormDataPart("acl", model.fieldsToUseInPost.acl)
                .addFormDataPart("Content-Type", model.fieldsToUseInPost.ContentType)
                .addFormDataPart("x-amz-meta-ohmeid", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzMetaOhmeId)
                .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Credential", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzCredential)
                .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Algorithm", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzAlgorithm)
                .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Date", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzDate)
                .addFormDataPart("Policy", model.fieldsToUseInPost.Policy)
                .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Signature", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzSignature)
                .addFormDataPart("file", fileName, sourceFile.asRequestBody(mimeType.toMediaTypeOrNull()))
                .build()

            val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(model.s3Host).post(requestBody).build()
            val response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                viewModel.onUploadSuccessful()
            } else {
                viewModel.onUploadFailed()
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            viewModel.onUploadFailed()
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Comment: You should not try to get a file path from uri as even if you manage to do so you have no access if it is not your file as you have seen. Use the uri as the provider of that uri takes care for access.

Comment: Hello @blackapps thanks for responding, if I understand rightly what you said, if I pass uri for the File(uri), then it should give me correct file and file.canread should be true?

Comment: You understood me wrong. You cannot use the File class for uries. You got an uri and with that read access. Probably write access too. You do not need to mess around with any permission first.

Comment: the main reason for getting the File is so the file can be uploaded to server. just to give you an idea I had added the function `uploadFile()` which requires the File to be uploaded. If I cannot get the File from the above methods (it has read exception) but what do you think should be done

Comment: You can use the uri to upload the file. So many people had the same problem as you. Google for inputstreamrequestbody.

Comment: ohh thank you so much, I will look into it

Comment: do you have any example of it please